# Binding вложенному свойству

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Приведу пример кода:

```
public class Node : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ISource Source { get; set; }        
    public string Name => Source.Setting.Name;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

И привязка:

```
<TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

Для привязки используется Fody. Проблема в следующем: При изменении внешним кодом значения Source.Setting.Name, Name в классе Node не бросает OnChange() и естественно вьюшка не обновляется. Конечно, можно в xaml сделать привязку к Source.Setting.Name и тогда проблем не будет, но это мне не подходит, поскольку вместо ISource может быть другой класс и свойство Name будет лежать по другому пути..
Так же можно создать событие и бросать его в сеттере свойства Source.Setting.Name, однако хотелось бы избежать подобного.

Вопрос. Как мне вызвать OnChange() у Name при изменении Source.Setting.Name?
Возможно, изначально всё сделано неверно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Setting его реализовывает. Даже если вручную в сеттере свойства Source.Setting.Name вызвать OnChange(), то ничего не срабатывает.. В дебагере видно, что Name у объекта Node изменился, но вьюшка его не перерисовывает, поскольку у него тоже нужно вызвать OnChange()

Comment: Ааа, я понял вашу проблему. А `Setting` внутри `Source` может меняться?

Comment: `Source` задается один раз или тоже может меняться?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, нет, ни Setting, ни Source измениться не могут. Меняется лишь Source.Setting.Name, в соответствии с которым сразу же меняется Name в Node, однако он не бросает OnChange().. 
В Fody есть [DependsOn("Название поля")], которое позволяет автоматически вызвать OnChange() у зависимых свойств, если свойство изменилось, но тут они находятся в разных классах и такое не прокатывает..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. у вас `Source` не меняется, рекомендую его фактически неизменяемым и сделать, это позволит оформить подписку один раз в конструкторе (иначе придется отписываться от старого экземпляра и подписываться на новый в сеттере свойства):

```
public class Node : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ISource Source { get; }        

    ...
```

Теперь, в конструкторе:

```
    public Node(ISource source)
    {
        Source = source;
        Source.Setting.PropertyChanged += (s, args) =>
        {
            if (args.PropertyName == nameof(ISetting.Name))
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        };
    }
```

Т.е. мы вручную перехватываем сообщения об изменениях свойства `Name` в `Setting` и говорим GUI что надо перечитать и наше `Name`.